# Uso de multiplas teclas no Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

OK, editei a pergunta, este é o exemplo mais simplificado, 
eu queria que enquanto a tecla '6' estiver sendo pressionada, 
mesmo utilizando a tecla '8', ela continue interagindo com o programa, 
enquanto que a '8' apenas execute um comando e não interrompa a outra.

#

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame
Tela_principal = Tk()
Tela_principal.geometry('1024x720+10+10')
def aplicacao():
    area_1.place(x=0, y=0), area_2.place(x=3, y=150)
    fundo_area2.place(x=10, y=10)
    persona()
def execucao():
    Tela_principal.bind("<KeyPress-8>", controles)
    Tela_principal.bind("<KeyPress-5>", controles)
    Tela_principal.bind("<KeyPress-6>", controles)
    Tela_principal.bind("<KeyPress-4>", controles)
    fundo_area2.delete('personagem')
    persona()
    area_2.after(FPS, execucao)
def persona():
    boneco_tronco_Lateral = fundo_area2.create_polygon(
        [(2 + x, 25 + y), (20 + x, 25 + y), (20 + x, 152 + y), (2 + x, 152 + y)],
        fill=pele, outline='black', tag='personagem')
def controles(event):
    global x, y, velocidade_x, velocidade_y
    if event.char == '6':
        x += velocidade_x
        fundo_area2.move('personagem', velocidade_x, 0)
    if event.char == '4':
        x -= velocidade_x
        fundo_area2.move('personagem', -velocidade_x, 0)
    if event.char == '8' and '6':
        y -= velocidade_y
        x += velocidade_x
        fundo_area2.move('personagem', -velocidade_x, 0)
area_1 = Frame(bg='snow', height=100, width=780, cursor='cross')
fundo_area1 = Canvas(area_1, bg='plum4', height=43, width=620)
area_2 = Frame(bg='snow', height=500, width=1016, cursor='dotbox')
fundo_area2 = Canvas(area_2, bg='gray', height=642, width=973)
x = 0
y = 100
pele = 'tomato'
velocidade_x = 0.5
velocidade_y = 0.5
FPS = 5
cont_salto = 0
aplicacao(), execucao()
Tela_principal.mainloop()
```

###########Valeu!!

Comment: Você poderia fazer um exemplo mínimo replicável? Veja instruções aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Claro, vou postar um novo exemplo, mais simplificado.

Answer (score 0):

Dá para criar um set com todas a teclas pressionadas.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame
Tela_principal = Tk()
Tela_principal.geometry('1024x720+10+10')

keys = set()

def keyPressHandler(event):
    keys.add(event.char)
    controles()

def keyReleaseHandler(event):
    keys.remove(event.char)
    controles()

def aplicacao():
    area_1.place(x=0, y=0), area_2.place(x=3, y=150)
    fundo_area2.place(x=10, y=10)
    persona()
def execucao():
    Tela_principal.bind_all('<KeyPress>', keyPressHandler)
    Tela_principal.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', keyReleaseHandler)
    fundo_area2.delete('personagem')
    persona()
    area_2.after(FPS, execucao)
def persona():
    boneco_tronco_Lateral = fundo_area2.create_polygon(
        [(2 + x, 25 + y), (20 + x, 25 + y), (20 + x, 152 + y), (2 + x, 152 + y)],
        fill=pele, outline='black', tag='personagem')
def controles():
    global x, y, velocidade_x, velocidade_y
    if '8' in keys and '6' in keys:
        y -= velocidade_y
        x += velocidade_x
        fundo_area2.move('personagem', -velocidade_x, 0)
    elif '6' in keys:
        x += velocidade_x
        fundo_area2.move('personagem', velocidade_x, 0)
    elif '4' in keys:
        x -= velocidade_x
        fundo_area2.move('personagem', -velocidade_x, 0)
    elif '8' in keys:
        y -= velocidade_y
        fundo_area2.move('personagem', -velocidade_x, 0)

area_1 = Frame(bg='snow', height=100, width=780, cursor='cross')
fundo_area1 = Canvas(area_1, bg='plum4', height=43, width=620)
area_2 = Frame(bg='snow', height=500, width=1016, cursor='dotbox')
fundo_area2 = Canvas(area_2, bg='gray', height=642, width=973)
x = 0
y = 100
pele = 'tomato'
velocidade_x = 0.5
velocidade_y = 0.5
FPS = 5
cont_salto = 0
aplicacao(), execucao()
Tela_principal.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma `Thread` para executar as duas funções imultaneamente.
Exemplo:

```
from threading import Thread

thread1 = Thread(target=func1)
thread1.start()

thread2 = Thread(target=func2)
thread2.start()
```